# @tinymce/tinymce-angular@^3.0.0 <editor> is not loading second time visiting the page in Angular 8

Tags: angular, tinymce, rich-text-editor, tinymce-plugins

I was working for the issue since 4 days and won't able to find any solution yet.
I have an Angular application (version 8) and I am using @tinymce/tinymce-angular@^3.0.0 in it. for very first time I am able to see  is working properly. When I navigate to other screen and get back to editor screen again then I am getting following error.

**TypeError:** Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')
at P1 (tinymce.min.js?apiKey=9p4tysbn4x2f7uwv6i5f3xp9a44nxajs74tba05e9qx829ho:9:335700)
[image]

**FYI, if I refresh the page then I can see the < editor> is working.**
[image]

**Possible root cause:** Tinymce < editor> reference was not getting clear during navigating to other page, that's why next time when we get back to the page it is throwing an error.

[image]